# how to add file upload feature in woocommerce registration form?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I tried this but this code only add few input fields i want to add file upload feature.
if i change input type text it shows file option and also select file as well but not upload and get.
Please help me thanks

```
<p class="form-row form-row-first">
  <label for="reg_billing_first_name">
    <?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
</p>
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
  <label for="reg_billing_last_name">
    <?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="reg_billing_phone">
    <?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }


    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Phone is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );

function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        // WordPress default first name field.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing first name.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        // WordPress default last name field.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );

        // WooCommerce billing last name.
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        // WooCommerce billing phone
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );
```

Comment: Did you see this https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-upload-my-file/ ? Maybe you can find some pointers in there?

Comment: yes but This plugin adds the possibility to upload a file after an order is completed and attached it to that order.